# Adding C# code inline to aspx file generates VS 2008 compile error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

The inline code

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < ThumbnailList.Items.Count; i++)
{ Response.Write("thumbnailViews[" + i.ToString() + "] = $find('" + 
ThumbnailList.Items[i].FindControl("ThumbnailView").ClientID + "');\n"); } %>
```

produces a bunch of compile time errors in Visual Studio 2008 - although it works fine.

But this seems to be the exact way inline code should be added, at least according to this MS help file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(VS.80).aspx

The errors are:

- expected expression (at "<%")
- expected ';' (at "int i")
- expected ')' (at ThumbnailList.Items.Count;
- expected ';' (at " i++)")

I have done a

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  ...
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: i'm gonna take a stab and say it's probably the concatination into multiple lines that's causing the problem

Comment: can you post the code that's around this script?  Maybe there's something interfering with the C# block?

Comment: Marek - Above it is just some js variable definitions and a JS function declaration.  Below it is some JS code.

Comment: Jonezy - I did this just to make it easier to read on stackoverflow.  Actual code doesn't have embedded line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but it does address the problem of using inline code in that manner.

If a client script (I assume that's what you're trying to make here) seems to require inline asp.net code, I'd suggest moving it to the code behind and start using the ClientScriptManager class.

A good place to start would be:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx

Good luck!